# Can the DAO hack solution proposed by Vitalik be rejected by 51% of PoW miners?

Tags: the-dao, dao

If the majority of the network does not like the softfork, followed by the hardfork idea proposed by Vitalik (because they feel like the solution is an assault on immutability of ETH or for some other reason) can it be forced on the network?

http://pastebin.com/xW16N7Ye

> "The development community is proposing a soft fork, (with NO
>   ROLLBACK; no transactions or blocks will be “reversed”) which will
>   make any transactions that make any calls/callcodes/delegatecalls that
>   execute code with code hash
>   `0x7278d050619a624f84f51987149ddb439cdaadfba5966f7cfaea7ad44340a4ba`
>   (ie. the DAO and children) lead to the transaction (not just the call,
>   the transaction) being invalid, starting from block 1760000 (precise
>   block number subject to change up until the point the code is
>   released), preventing the ether from being withdrawn by the attacker
>   past the 27-day window. This will later be followed up by a hard fork
>   which will give token holders the ability to recover their ether."

Comment: Not even 51 % . Miners representing X % of the chain hash power can always secede and create their chain. Follow who wants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't be forced. The devs can only offer code, not force everyone to run it.

In addition, the devs are perfectly happy to let the community make the decision. See the statements by Vitalik and a geth core dev:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4oj7ql/personal_statement_regarding_the_fork/

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4ojsjm/personal_statement_from_one_geth_core_developer/

Even if the Foundation tried to force a particular change, the Foundation doesn't produce the only client. Ethcore for example has another client. They're currently offering a version that rolls back the theft, and again are leaving it up to the community to decide.

https://blog.ethcore.io/attack-on-thedao-what-will-be-your-response/